# Is there a more efficient way to sort two numbers?

Tags: c++

I want `dLower` and `dHigher` to have the lower and higher of two double values, respectively - i.e. to sort them if they are the wrong way around. The most immediate answer, it seems is:

```
void ascending(double& dFirst, double& dSecond)
{
    if(dFirst > dSecond)
        swap(dFirst,dSecond);
}

ascending(dFoo, dBar);
```

But it seems like such an obvious thing to do I wondered if I'm just not using the right terminology to find a standard routine.

Also, how would you make that generic?

Comment: In the context of sorting networks, I think this is called a "comparison-swap". Note that "compare-and-swap" is a completely different thing, so you're right that terminology is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good way of approaching it. It is as efficient as you are going to get. <strike>I doubt that this specific function has a generally recognized name.</strike> This is apparently called comparison-swap.

Generalizing it on type is as easy as:

```
template <typename T>
void ascending(T& dFirst, T& dSecond)
{
    if (dFirst > dSecond)
        std::swap(dFirst, dSecond);
}
```

---

Corroborating this function:

```
int main() {
    int a=10, b=5;
    ascending(a, b);
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;

    double c=7.2, d=3.1;
    ascending(c, d);
    std::cout << c << ", " << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
5, 10
3.1, 7.2
```

Answer (score 5):

Playing the "extremely generic" game:

```
template <typename T, typename StrictWeakOrdering>
void comparison_swap(T &lhs, T &rhs, StrictWeakOrdering cmp) {
    using std::swap;
    if (cmp(rhs, lhs)) {
        swap(lhs, rhs);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void comparison_swap(T &lhs, T &rhs) {
    comparison_swap(lhs, rhs, std::less<T>());
}
```

This ticks the following boxes:

- uses a less-than comparator, which is more likely to be readily available for a user-defined type, since it's used in standard algorithms.
- Comparator is *optionally* configurable, and defaults to something sensible (you could use `std::greater<T>` as the default if you prefer and modify accordingly). It's also guaranteed valid for arbitrary pointers of the same type, which `operator<` isn't.
- Uses either a specialization of `std::swap`, or a `swap` function found by ADL, just in case the type T provides one but not the other.

There may be some boxes I've forgotten about, though.

Comment: +1, but I would use default arguments instead of overloading.

Comment: @Steve M: Go ahead and try, bearing in mind that a function template cannot have default template arguments ;-p

Comment: Ugh, I always forget about that!

Comment: @Steve M: So did I. My mnemonic is, "the standard defines two templates for a reason", but I always forget the mnemonic too until I actually try it and get the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Let me throw a special case in here that only applies if performance is a absolutely critical issue there and if float accuracy is enough: You could consider the vector pipeline (if your target CPU has one).

Some CPUs can get you the min and max of each component of a vector with one instruction each, so you can process 4 values in one go - without any branches at all.

Again, this is a very special case and most likely not relevant for what you're doing, but I wanted to bring this up since "more efficient" was part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers apart from EboMike's focus on programming generality and use the same underlying compare-and-swap approach. I'm interested in this question because it would be nice to have specialisations that avoid branching for pipelining efficiency. I'm sketching out some untested/unbenchmarked implementations that might compile more efficiently than the previous answers by exploiting conditional-move instructions (e.g., `cmovl`) to avoid branching. I have no idea if this manifests in real-world performance gains, however...

Programming generality could be added by making these specialisations, using the compare-and-swap approach in the generic case. This is a common enough problem that I would really love to see it correctly implemented as a set of architecture-tuned specialisations in a library.

I've included x86 assembly output from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/65516s) in comments.

```
/*
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi]
        cmp     eax, ecx
        mov     edx, ecx
        cmovl   edx, eax
        cmovl   eax, ecx
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], edx
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], eax
        ret
*/
void ascending1(int &a, int &b)
{
  bool const pred = a < b;
  int const _a = pred ? a : b;
  int const _b = pred ? b : a;
  a = _a;
  b = _b;
}


/*
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsi]
        mov     edx, ecx
        xor     edx, eax
        cmp     eax, ecx
        cmovle  ecx, eax
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], ecx
        xor     ecx, edx
        mov     dword ptr [rsi], ecx
        ret
*/
void ascending2(int &a, int &b)
{
  bool const pred = a < b;
  int const c = a^b;
  a = pred ? a : b;
  b = a^c;
}


/*
The following implementation changes to a function-style interface,
which I feel is more elegant, although admittedly always forces assignment
to occur, so will be more expensive if assignment is costly.
See foobar() to see that this rather nicely inlines.

        mov     eax, esi
        mov     ecx, esi
        xor     ecx, edi
        cmp     edi, esi
        cmovle  eax, edi
        xor     ecx, eax
        shl     rcx, 32
        or      rax, rcx
        ret
*/
std::pair<int,int> ascending3(int const a, int const b)
{
  bool const pred = a < b;
  int const c = a^b;
  int const x = pred ? a : b;
  int const y = c^x;
  return std::make_pair(x,y);
}


/*
This is to show that ascending3() inlines very nicely
to only 5 assembly instructions.
        # inlined ascending3().
        mov     eax, esi
        xor     eax, edi
        cmp     edi, esi
        cmovle  esi, edi
        xor     eax, esi
        # end of inlining.
        add     eax, esi
        ret
*/
int foobar(int const a, int const b)
{
    auto const [x,y] = ascending3(a,b);
    return x+y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use std::sort() with a lambda or a functor?

Comment: Because it would be like killing a gnat by employing an intercontinental H-bomb missile?

Comment: Really? I thought that once compiled it was optimized inlined by the compiler and then it would mean that it's just a "free implementation" available immediately and that works fine and efficiently in almost all cases. That's not like if intercontinental H-bomb missile were accessible to anybody...

Comment: try writing it out, see how your implementation of `ascending` looks next to the OP's.

Comment: Ah ok what I didn't understood was that there is only 2 values, while I was thinking about a generic usage of "ascending".

Answer (score 1):

As you also asked,

> Is there a more efficient way to sort
>   two numbers?

Considering efficiency, you may need to write your own swap function and test its performance against std::swap.

Here is Microsoft implementation.

```
template<class _Ty> inline
    void swap(_Ty& _Left, _Ty& _Right)
    {   // exchange values stored at _Left and _Right
    if (&_Left != &_Right)
        {   // different, worth swapping
        _Ty _Tmp = _Left;

        _Left = _Right;
        _Right = _Tmp;
        }
    }
```

If you feel the condition `if (&_Left != &_Right)` check is not required, you can ommit it to improve the performance of the code. You can write your own swap like below.

```
template <class T>
inline void swap(T &left, T& right)
{
    T temp = left;
    left = right;
    right = temp;
}
```

For me it looks like improved performance slightly for 10 crore calls.
Anyways, you need to measure performance related changes properly. Don't assume.

Some library functions may not run so fast as they are written considering generic usage, error checking etc. If performance is not critical in your application, it is recommended to use Library functions as they are well tested.

If performance is critical like hard realtime systems, there is nothing wrong in writing your own and use.